# How to use maven assembly plugin to generate output directories having name like project-git_commit_hash?

Tags: java, git, maven

I have looked at https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin, I am trying to find ways to make my output tar.gz or directories getting a name appended with the git commit hash.

Please suggest a way to do this.

Comment: What have you done so far? How does your current approach look like which does not what you like to achieve?

Comment: @khmarbaise Currently, my output tar.gz doesn't have git commit hash appended to it. What i do now is, use the generated git.properties from git commit-id-plugin and rename the tar.gz during deployment. I am trying ways to do this using the assembly plugin itself.

Comment: Not exact same as your question, well very similar: Include git commit hash in jar version via `git-commit-id-plugin` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40446275/include-git-commit-hash-in-jar-version