# Include git commit hash in jar version

Tags: java, maven, maven-versions-plugin

I'm using maven and my goal is to include the git commit hash in the version number. Something like : 1.1.{git_hash}.

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://www.jayway.com/2012/04/07/continuous-deployment-versioning-and-git/).

Q: is it possible to somehow override the version number specified in the version element of the pom file?

Answer (score 59):

One way to achieve this is to use the [git-commit-id-plugin](https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin). Add this to the list of plugins in the `build` section of your pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${git-commit-id-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>get-the-git-infos</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>revision</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>validate</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <dotGitDirectory>${project.basedir}/.git</dotGitDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Note, that I've changed the phase to `validate`, so the revision number property is already available in when the artifact is packaged.

Then, add the following to the `build` section:

```
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${git.commit.id.describe-short}</finalName>
    <!-- your list of plugins -->
</build>
```

The `git.commit.id.describe-short` property is produced by the `git-commit-id-plugin`. It contains current git revision number (shortened to 7 digits) and an optional `dirty` indicator.

The produced artifact will look like this: `examplelib-1.0.2-efae3b9.jar` (or `examplelib-1.0.2-efae3b9-dirty.jar` in case there are uncommitted changes on your repository).

Additionally, you might also want to put this information to the MANIFEST.MF of your artifact. In such case add this to your list of plugins (the example assumes the artifact is a `jar`):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
                <SCM-Revision>${git.commit.id.describe-short}</SCM-Revision>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

---

Additional remarks:

1. I've shown a simple configuration of the `git-commit-id-plugin`. On their site you may find more options and properties. In addition to properties, that can be used inside pom.xml, the plugin can also generate a properties file containing information about revision.
2. As an alternative to `git-commit-id-plugin`, you might prefer [buildnumber-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/usage.html). In order to get revision numbers this plugin requires a [SCM](https://maven.apache.org/components/scm/maven-scm-plugin/usage.html) plugin also configured in your pom.xml.
3. This setup may interfere with other plugins that transform or rename your artifacts (in my case it was the maven-shade-plugin - one of the sources jar it produces did not contain proper revision number).

Comment: how did you make it work?
the variables are not being exposed to the `pom` and I get the message: The template variable 'git.commit.id.describe-short' has no value

Comment: In the 'git-commit-id-plugin' definition I've changed the execution phase to 'validate', so the revision number property is already available when the artifact is packaged.

Comment: Note that the resources filtering is important for this plugin to work, don't omit it! (`<filtering>true</filtering>`)

Comment: _"Even though this plugin tries to be compatible with every Maven version there are some known limitations with specific versions."_ Check this [compatibility table](https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin#plugin-compatibility-with-maven).

Comment: make sure you have not excluded the properties(in plugin configuration) you refer in  finalName, for example, if you have only exposed 'git.commit.id.abbrev' use only 

<finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${git.commit.id.abbrev}</finalName>

Answer (score 8):

The above accepted answer didn't work for me. I found the link https://dzone.com/articles/maven-git-commit-id-plugin, from where I copied the plugin code below. It worked first time for me. I now have the git.properties file automatically included in my target JAR file. Very useful for tracking.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2.4</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>get-the-git-infos</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>revision</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
    <dotGitDirectory>${project.basedir}/.git</dotGitDirectory>
    <prefix>git</prefix>
    <verbose>false</verbose>
    <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
    <generateGitPropertiesFilename>${project.build.outputDirectory}/git.properties</generateGitPropertiesFilename>
    <format>json</format>
    <gitDescribe>
        <skip>false</skip>
        <always>false</always>
        <dirty>-dirty</dirty>
    </gitDescribe>
</configuration>
```

Add finalName to build section to also have the version in the target file name

```
<build>

<finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${git.commit.id.describe-short}</finalName>

...

</build>
```

Comment: The problem I'm having with this is that I'm using the shade library to create uber jars. The ID plugin only tags the normal jar file, which is useless