# GitLab CI/CD and GitLab Package Registry - change maven artifact name during deployment

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to create my first GitLab CI pipeline which will deploy Maven artifact to the GitLab Package Registry following that [example](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Maven.gitlab-ci.yml).

My question is how can I change artifact name (append to it) during the deployment stage as `APP_PACKAGE_SNAPSHOT` which I have defined in the init stage as variable

ini:

```
  stage: init
  script:
    - APP_VERSION=$(mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout)
    - APP_PACKAGE_NAME=$(mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.artifactId -q -DforceStdout)
    - APP_PACKAGE_SNAPSHOT="SNAPSHOT-$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA"
```

when pipeline was executed from the develop branch.

Comment: Is there a reason for you not to use `build.finalName` to change the artifact name? See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40446275/include-git-commit-hash-in-jar-version) for an example.

Comment: @slauth Yes, because of `$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA`. In the Jenkins pipeline was easier to do that part.

Comment: I'd argue that using the `git-commit-id-plugin` is not that much harder.

Comment: @slauth yeah, but I want to have it only added for specific branches not for the main

Comment: I see. Sorry, I must have missed that part.