# Maven - Versioning the Project

Tags: java, maven, version, versioning, build-numbers

I'm trying to learn more about how big project builds are being versioned by developer teams using maven. For example, some projects have versions like: 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT-g57517b7, what that "g57517b7" represents exactly? and is it possible to automate versioning process that increments those number or some kind of build number on maven?

Comment: A version number like that is typically a version control fingerprint; e.g. the first part of a git commit checksum.   So `2.0.0-SNAPSHOT-g57517b7` is likely to represent a prerelease (i.e. SNAPSHOT) build for 2.0.0 corresponding to commit `g57517b7`.

Answer (score 1):

The last part of the version name looks like a current git commit id.
Have a look here [Include git commit hash in jar version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40446275/include-git-commit-hash-in-jar-version)